# Pulling up a list of users who your not following using your controller (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I'm new to ruby on rails so please forgive the question. I tried looking at the Rails guide and a few similar questions - and I'm 90% there I feel. Currently, I can pull up the list of users that excludes current user - but my work doesn't exclude the users that I followed which is what I want also. I am trying to show for a specific user a list of users who he or she has not yet followed. I have listed below all my relevant code down below. Thank you so much guys!!

**Users controller**

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@random = User.find((User.pluck(:id) - [@user.id] - [@user.following.ids]).shuffle.first)
end
```

**Show.html.erb**

```
<div>
<%= image_tag @random.avatar, width: 38, class: "css-style" %>&nbsp<strong><%= link_to @random.username, @random, class: "youmaylikelink" %></strong>
</div>
```

**Rails Console**
In my rails console if I do @user.following.ids > I get the ids for the users that the current user is following. That is why I put @user.following.ids in my users controller.

Comment: Maybe get the last part out of these [ ]. You are using an array that has one array element in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `@user.following.ids` is already an array, thus there is no need to wrap it in one. Hence:

```
User.find((User.pluck(:id) - [@user.id]  - @user.following.ids).shuffle.first)
```

---

Still, this fetches all user ids, which on production database would be problematic. You could instead select only a single record:

```
User.where.not(id: [@user.id] + @user.following.ids).first
```

How to do the shuffle is database specific. For *postgresql* and *sqlite3*, you could do:

```
User.where.not(id: [@user.id] + @user.following.ids).order('RANDOM()').first
```

Comment: thank you so much!! this was such a helpful explanation - also thank you for letting me know about the production database issue

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `find` instead use `where`.
If your are using `rails 4+` then
`User.where.not(id: [[@user.id] + @user.following.ids])` will return all the user excluding `@user` and `@user.following`

Even you can write as `User.where.not(id: [[@user] + @user.following])`

Now you can make any operation on it. Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you for your response, greatly appreciate it champ. Thanks for telling me about that rails 4+ feature

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code. No need to find the user as well.

```
User.where.not(id: [[current_user.id] + current_user.following.ids]).shuffle.first
```

Comment: Bharat thank you for your response, greatly appreciate it sir